# Is there a way to increase usb power detection sensitivity?

Tags: usb, power-on

I am looking for a way to have my phone register a usb power connection sooner or more reliably.

I need the phone to register a signal through the usb as soon as it reads any kind of power fluctuation if possible. I have two options for the power source: a constant power and a pulsating power source. I can get the device to register it with the constant power but it takes a while to work. So i need one of the following.

1. to reduce the time it registers the power.
2. to reduce the sensitivity and it triggers more easily.
3. to send power over the data wires instead of the power wires to make the device think its receiving a data signal. I would need to know how much power could be used across the data cables but I don't know if that is even possible.

Note: its not to use for data or powering the device. I just need it to act as a sort of relay to activate applications.

Also, I tried the pulsating power on my nexus 7 and it worked great but when i tried it on the device i wanted to use it with, it didn't detect the pulsating power. Maybe the Nexus device has more sensitive settings or perhaps it has a better capacitor etc.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This question is better asked at SE Electrical, IMO, after reading their help and rewording